# Displaying proportionally spaced numbers (instead of monospace / tabular) on iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, uifont, uifontdescriptor

I am rendering numbers in iOS (targeting 7 and up) by storing them in an NSAttributedString and rendering with "drawAtPoint:". I am using Helvetica Neue.

I have noticed that **digits of numbers drawn like this are not proportional** – the glyphs all have the same width. Even a skinny "1" takes up the same space as a "0".

A test confirms this:

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
  NSString *iString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i];
  const CGSize iSize = [iString sizeWithAttributes: [self attributes]];
  NSLog(@"Size of %d is %f", i, iSize.width);
}
```

With, elsewhere:

```
-(NSDictionary *) attributes
{
  static NSDictionary * attributes;
  if(!attributes)
  {
    attributes = @{
                   NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11],
                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                   };
  }
  return attributes;
}
```

This resulting glyphs **all have the same width** of 6.358 points.

Is there some rendering option I can turn on that to **enable proportional digit glyphs**? Is there another font (ideally similar to Helvetica Neue) that supports proportional digit glyphs (ideally, built in)? Anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a discussion about the use of proportional verses "tabular" (another term for monospace) "figures" and "numerals" at [link](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/proportional-vs-tabular-figures). By searching with that terminology I found this [link](http://typographica.org/on-typography/beyond-helvetica-the-real-story-behind-fonts-in-ios-7/) on iOS 7 font rendering, which I think will let me self answer this. I'll update when done.

Comment: This pdf [link](http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2013/session_223__using_fonts_with_text_kit.pdf) of slides from an Apple presentations provides the code needed. Important to know is that to use these features you must to `#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>`: that's where the symbols are defined.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

iOS 7 lets you specify fonts using `UIFontDescriptor` instances. A `UIFont` instance is then obtained from a descriptor.

Given a `UIFontDescriptor` it is also possible to obtain a customisation of it that changes some characteristics by using the method `[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes: attibutes]` where `attributes` is an `NSDictionary` of font attributes.

Apple documents the attributes in the [`UIFontDescriptor` reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

From the reference, one particular font descriptor attribute `UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute` lets you provide  "An array of dictionaries representing non-default font feature settings. Each dictionary contains `UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey` and `UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey`."

Documentation of the `UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey`s and `UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey`s is in [Apple's Font Registry documentation](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/registry/). The specific case of proportional digits is covered in this [pdf of slides of an Apple presentation](http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2013/session_223__using_fonts_with_text_kit.pdf), so I just lifted that.

This code that will take an existing `UIFont` instance and give you back a new instance with proportional digits:

```
// You'll need this somewhere at the top of your file to pull
// in the required constants.
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

…

UIFont *const existingFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor *const existingDescriptor = [existingFont fontDescriptor];

NSDictionary *const fontAttributes = @{
 // Here comes that array of dictionaries each containing UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey 
 // and UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey that the reference mentions.
 UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: @[
     @{
       UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberSpacingType),
       UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kProportionalNumbersSelector)
      }]
 };

UIFontDescriptor *const proportionalDescriptor = [existingDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes: fontAttributes];
UIFont *const proportionalFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor: proportionalDescriptor size: [existingFont pointSize]];
```

You could add this as a category on `UIFont` if you wished, etc.

Edit note: thanks to Chris Schwerdt for the improvements.

Comment: _+1_ Don’t forget to import CoreText for those constants.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll amend the code to add that as it had me scratching my head initially!

Comment: This isn't working for me, every number except for a 1 seems to be proportional. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it just be the font you're using, @TylerPfaff? I've not checked the widths of each glyph, so I might be getting the same thing – it seems to _look_ okay though :-)

Comment: Values for the `UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey` and `UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey` can be found in `SFNTLayoutTypes.h`, which further references [Apple's Font Registry documentation](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/registry/).

Comment: Also, you can remove the `kCharacterAlternativesType` key. I believe it was used in that time formatting example to replace the square colon character with a rounded colon character and doesn't affect the number spacing.

Comment: @ChrisSchwerdt Thanks. I'll edit the answer to include your suggestions, unless you'd prefer to and get the edit credit?

Comment: @TylerPfaff I think that for the Helvetica Neue font, even with proportional digits, it is just the "1" glyph that is narrower. This is still a great improvement over completely tabular digits, though. Other fonts that support proportional digits might be different. (p.s. – "_proportional_" is where glyph widths _do_ vary, "_tabular_" or "_fixed width_" or "_monospace_" is where they _don't_ vary).

Comment: This option only works if you're using a font which supports this feature. If you're using a custom font, this may not work. The options that a font supports can be inspected with something like this: `NSLog(@"%@", CTFontCopyFeatures ( ( __bridge CTFontRef ) myFont ));`